# could you explain this db2 SQL ERROR: "Error occurred processing a conditional compilation directive near string. Reason code=r2

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, azure-ad-b2c, db2-400, db2-luw

could you please help why the following error raises when I call a stored procedure in db2  WITH 2 parameterS. the first refers to the schema source: P_S and the second to target schema: P_T

thank you in advance

Comment: could you please help why the following error raises when I call a stored procedure in db2 WITH 2 parameterS. the first refers to the schema source: P_S and the second to TTHE target schema: P_T. SQL Error [38501]: Application raised error or warning with diagnostic text: "SQL20521N  Error occurred processing a conditional compilation directi".. SQLCODE=-438, SQLSTATE=38501, DRIVER=4.26.14

Comment: __Which__ is your Db2-server platform ? Linux/Unix/Window (db2-luw) or i-series (db2-400). You tagged both.

Comment: Why did you tag azure-ad-b2c ?  Be careful with your tags.

Comment: Such errors may happen, if you use identifiers beginning with the underscore character (`_`). Db2 may try to interpret it as a erroneous "selection directive". Refer to [Conditional compilation](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/c0056403.html?pos=2)

Answer (score 1):

The stored procedure raised an exception explicitly. In other words it decided that there was some reason it could not continue with your request.

You will need to read the stored procedure source code to see the cause, and see  also the (optional) message text that stored procedures can link with an exception to give more details.

For [SQL20521N](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic24.html#sql20521n) reason code 2, the explanation is:
"The SQL compiler was processing a statement that included conditional
compilation directives. An error occurred at or near the statement text
given in the token "". Possible reasons are given by
the reason code. "

Reason code 2 means: A global variable reference in a selection directive is not defined as a constant.

As stackoverflow is a *programming* website, if you want more specific help, then you must either show your stored procedure code or show an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

For Db2-server on Linux/Unix Windows, read the description of SQLCODE -438 [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic2.html#sql0438n)

For Db2-server on i-series (as/400) , read the description of SQL0438 [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzala/rzalaml.htm).